# Converting PostgreSQL dump file into CSV files

Tags: postgresql, backup, csv, pg-dump, docker

I have a PostgreSQL database running in a docker container. I used the below command to get a dump file of the Postgres database - "docker exec -t your-db-container pg_dumpall -c -U postgres > dump_`date +%d-%m-%Y"_"%H_%M_%S`.sql". Since it's a docker volume , the database doesn't store on the machine to use psql COPY command and such.

I have multiple tables with different headers. I need to convert the dump file into a CSV file with the headers of the table. Can be a single or multiple CSV files.

Any other way of directly getting the CSV files from the docker container database will also be appreciated.

PS: I'm a beginner in this area and would really appreciate a detailed solution

Comment: One might use the `COPY` command to export data as CSV.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use 'COPY' command,try this:

```
COPY (SELECT * from table) To '/path/output.csv' With CSV;
```

Comment: I'm not able to use this as the database isn't storing on the machine.

Answer (score -1):

Using `pg_dump` with the `-t` flag could provide a plain text output for a table and you can increase the tables you need by adding that flag as much as needed. On the other hand getting a CSV output is only available via `psql` flag `--csv`.

So you can try

```
psql -d your_db -c 'select * from your_table' --csv
```

for your need.